# REST : return 'method not allowed' or not do the method?

Tags: rest, symfony

I'm building a restful API for my Symfony app.

I have a resource that can't be created via the API, so my first idea was to don't create the POST method/URI. But now I'm wondering if create the POST method and throw manually a `405 Method Not Allowed` is not a better idea.

Has anybody an idea of the best solution?

Comment: if you don't have any custom error requirement it is not necessary to create a method and throw the error, Default error will work

Comment: It certainly is not a bad idea.

Comment: The default error will be a 404 route not found. So you think it's better to throw a 404 than a 405 ?

Comment: @Rupesh the Default error is not explicit (is it not allowed, server problem, bad route ?), return a 405 status is more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other frameworks - e.g. spring in java or django rest framework in python - it's done automatically. If an HTTP method isn't listed the framework will automatically return a `405 Method Not Allowed`. It's very useful.

Personally I'd go for handling it manually - I mean returning a `405 Method Not Allowed` - to be explicit about the error. This is not the case that route does not exist, hence `404 Not Found` is a bad choice. It does exist, however not serving `POST`.

Even `403 Forbidden` will be much better than `404 Not Found`.

Comment: Ruby On Rails return 405 too

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll follow you ;)